# When querying data from Redis using StackExchange.Redis, the data returned from the keys is wrong

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

When querying keys in Redis, we encountered an issue where the value returned from keys looked to be the results of other Redis commands. e.g. we saw the values 'OK', 'PONG' and '# Replication\r\nrole:master...'

We did have a failing healthcheck around the same time as we first saw this issue in the logs, although the application almost immediately reconnected to the Redis cluster.

Struggling to replicate the issue as this happened a single time on our production instance causing a short outage, and restarting our application seemed to resolve the issue.

Could this be a threading or context switching issue in stackexchange.redis or in our application where the wrong responses are returned from the connection to Redis?

We aren't using connection pooling currently.